# How do I add a RadToolTip to a JQuery dynamically generated table cell text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, telerik

How do I add a Radtooltip to a text that appears in a dynamically created table cell using JQuery.  The Tooltip popup should show the data from the cell along with a hyperlink.  This is for a table displaying issues and the tooltip is suppose to display a link taking use to a resolution page.

```
function GenerateProblemResoultionLinks() {
// Open up the landing page for addressing the problem.
     function problemLink_Click() {
// Get the problem data from the row.
    var $self = $telerik.$(this);
    var oProblemData = JSON.parse(
    $self.attr("data-Problem")
    );
// Add the original message to the problem data.
    oProblemData["problemText"] = $self
        .text()
    .trim();
// Convert the object back to JSON and encode it for transport.
    var strProblemDataArgument = encodeURIComponent(
    JSON.stringify(oProblemData)    );
            var strURL =
            "problemresolutionpage.aspx?problemData=" + 
             strProblemDataArgument;
    window.open(strURL, "_blank");
    }
// Set up the delegated event handler.
    $telerik
    .$(".PROBLEMDETAILS> tbody")
    .on("click", ".problemLink", problemLink_Click);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by modifying my code as follows:

```
function GenerateProblemResoultionLinks() {

   function problemLink_Click() {
    // Get the problem data from the row.
        var $self = $telerik.$(this);
        var oProblemData = JSON.parse(
        $self.attr("data-integrationProblem")
        );
    // Add the original message to the problem data.
    oProblemData["problemText"] = $self
        .text()
        .trim();

         if (oProblemData){                    
          // Generate problem soltuion tooltip for each problem type. Needs to stay within the scope of the onclick. 
              switch(oProblemData.type){
               case "ProblemType1": 
                  var IDForSolution1=oProblemData.data["layoutIDT"]; 
                  var IDForSolution2 = oProblemData.data["keywordTableIDT"];
                  var Soltuion1Link="<a href=pageforsoltuion1.aspx?item="+ IDForSolution1 +" target=\"_blank\">UpdateItem</a>";
                  var Solution2Link="<a href=pageforsolution2.aspx?record="+ IDForSolution2 +" target=\"_blank\">Add New Record</a>";                 
                  var toolTipTMsg ="A new record may be added to the record table <br/> OR<br/> item can be updated in the item table."
                  var radToolTip = $find("<%= RadToolTip1.ClientID %>");
                           radToolTip.set_targetControl(this); 
                           radToolTip.set_content("<p>" +toolTipTMsg +"</p>-------------------</br>" + Soltuion1Link +"<br/>"+ Soltuion2Link);
                           radToolTip.show();
                        break;
                      default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
           }
            // Set up the delegated event handler.
            $telerik
                .$(".IMPORTEXPORTDETAILS > tbody")
                .on("click", ".problemLink", problemLink_Click);
        }
```

and I added the following as well:

```
<telerik:RadToolTip RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadToolTip1" runat="server" Title="Problem Solution(s)" IsClientID="true" Callout="false" RelativeTo="Element" Position="MiddleRight" ShowEvent="FromCode" Height="220" Width="300" HideEvent="LeaveToolTip">
</telerik:RadToolTip>
```